# Getting the Settlement ID from the Finance API at Amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm using Amazon MWS to retrieve financial events from my seller account.

I can't seem to find anywhere in the response the financial events Settlement ID that appears on the standard settlement reports.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Settlements automatically come with reports that are available through MWS. Those reports have the `_GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE_` type and can be listed through `GetReportList()`. Please note that the report's ID does not match the settlement id. You'll have to request the report through `GetReport()` - the settlement ID is part of the response.

Comment: I know that. my question is not on the settlement report but rather on retrieving financial transactions from the finance API https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/147-6699201-8934835?ie=UTF8&group=finances&section=finances&version=latest

Comment: We're you able to figure this out? I'm currently attempting to get financed data by groups. I'm wondering if the group's match up with the settlement.